# Duplicates for some rows after left join and custom layout

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a query:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT
  categories.category,
  categories.attempts,
  categories.count,
  categories.completed,
  words.username,
  words.correct,
  words.errors,
  words.word,
  words.corrections,
  words.b64
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN words
ON categories.category=words.category";
```

I then push into an array:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con3, $sql3);
$WandC = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($WandC, array(
        "category" => $row["category"],
        "username" => $row["username"],
        "attempts" => $row["attempts"],
        "completed" => $row["completed"],
        "count" => $row["count"],
        "correct" => $row["correct"],
        "errors" => $row["errors"],
        "corrections" => $row["corrections"],
        "word" => $row["word"],
        "image" => $row["b64"]
        )
    );
}
```

This gives me:

```
1 {category: "cvc", username: "bob", attempts: "8", completed: "0", count: "8", …}
2 {category: "cvc", username: "bob", attempts: "210", completed: "1", count: "3", …}
3 {category: "cvc", username: "bob", attempts: "8", completed: "0", count: "8", …}
4 {category: "cvc", username: "emma", attempts: "210", completed: "1", count: "3", …}
5 {category: "cvc", username: "emma", attempts: "8", completed: "0", count: "8", …} ...
```

Then I change the layout with:

```
$response3 = [];

foreach($WandC as $W) {
    if(empty(@$response3['all'][$W['category']][$W['username']])) {
        $response3['all'][$W['category']][$W['username']] = [
            'count' =>      $W['count'],
            'attempts' =>   $W['attempts'],
            'completed' =>  $W['completed']
        ];
    }

    $response3['all'][$W['category']][$W['username']]['word'][$W['word']] = [
        'correct' =>        $W['correct'],
        'errors' =>         $W['errors'],
        'corrections' =>    $W['corrections'],
        'image' =>    $W['image'],
    ];
}
```

Which gives me:

```
bob:

   attempts: "210"

   completed: "1"

   count: "3"

   word: 

        cat: {correct: "1", errors: "2", corrections: "0", image: ""}

        mat: {correct: "1", errors: "2", corrections: "0", image: ""}

        top: {correct: "0", errors: "1", corrections: "0", image: ""}

emma:

   attempts: "210"

   completed: "1"

   count: "3"

   word: 

       cat: {correct: "1", errors: "0", corrections: "0", image: ""}

       mat: {correct: "1", errors: "0", corrections: "0", image: ""}

       top: {correct: "1", errors: "0", corrections: "0", image: ""}...
```

The layout is exactly how I need it. However "count", "attempts" and "completed" values are the same with every iteration, while the rest are correct. I need the attempts, completed, and count values to be in accordance with each username.

So, for this example:

```
    bob:

       attempts: "210"

       completed: "1"

       count: "3"
...

    emma:

       attempts: "8"

       completed: "0"

       count: "8"
...
```

What am I missing here? I think I am doing something wrong when pushing the first array before changing the layout.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* in question would help.

Comment: I have added more information, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: FIX: for anyone who may be interested, I found the issue: I simply had to left join on username instead of category. I thought because my layout was going to be lead by category that I would need to left join on it beforehand but that did not matter since the rearranging at the foreach fixes it regardless.